# What's nodes.js and should the web developer learn it?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to learn Javascript these days but a lot of people told me about something called nodes.js to learn too in Javascript...I'm sorry about my little knowledge..So please tell me about it..and is it important to learn !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically lets you run javascript on the server (with some additional libraries for things like file io, networking, etc).  The appeal is that you can write a web application in a single language on both the front and back side.

Comment: So do you advise me to learn it ? :)

Comment: Yes, I think it's definitely worth understanding.  Whether you use it on projects will depend on (a) what the constraints of the project are, and (b) if you want to use a technology that's been around longer (like php, java) that might have specific libraries you need.